Difficulty with getByLabelText in React
I have an input in a form with the following code...
<div className="Field" id="choose-date">
    <div className="field-title-icon">
        <label htmlFor="res-date">
            Choose date<sup>*</sup>
        </label>
        <img className="booking-icon" src={DateImage} alt="Calendar icon"></img>
    </div>

    <input type="date" value={date} onChange={handleDateChange} id="res-date" className={dateValid ? "valid-input"
        : "invalid-input" } aria-required="true" />
</div>

I'm trying to grab it for a test using the following code...
const dateInput = screen.getByLabelText("Choose date\*");
userEvent.type(dateInput, "2024-07-09");

but I keep getting:
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find a label with the text of: Choose date*"

I'm quite new to React and I've checked and double-checked the code to the best of my knowledge and I'm getting nowhere. Can someone help, please?

I guess the issue might happens because the label is "Choose date" instead of Choose date.

There are 2 issues here:

Use for instead of htmlFor. htmlFor is the method to access the value of for
The label's text isn't Choose date<sup>*</sup>. It's Choose date with another a sup node. You can use /Choose date/ to have a martial match.

So the changes will be:
<label for="res-date">
  Choose date<sup>*</sup>
</label>

and
screen.getByLabelText(/Choose date/)


Hi kevinluo201, thanks for the response. I made the changes you suggested, but I also realised that my test code wasn't actually rendering the component, and that's why it wasn't finding the label

@GordonMarshall so did the test pass after the code rendered successfully?

fyr, I used https://testing-playground.com/ to test your code : )
